# cant embed parents template in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class(userComponent) which derived from another class(DetailComponent) I debug and see everything works as I expected(no exception) except the thing; template of Detail component not rendered in UserComponent which I explicitly defined. Class and templates below;

ArtistlistComponent;

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Auth } from '../services/auth.service'
import { SpotfyService } from '../services/spotify.service'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-users',
    templateUrl: '../templates/user.component.html'
})
export class ArtistComponent {
    detailedArtist:any;
    artists: any;
    spotfyService: SpotfyService;
    showArtistDetails=false;
    constructor(private auth: Auth, spotfyService: SpotfyService) {
        this.spotfyService = spotfyService;
    }
    selectArtist(artistlink){
        debugger
        this.detailedArtist=artistlink;
    }
}
```

artistlist.component.html:

```
    <div class="row">
        <form class="form-horizontal" >
            <input id="searchby" class="from-control" >
        </form>
    </div>
<a (click)="selectArtist(artist.Id)">{{artist.name}}</a>
<artist-detail *ngIf="detailedArtist" artist="detailedArtist"></artist-detail>
```

detail.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Auth } from '../services/auth.service'
    import { SpotfyService } from '../services/spotify.service'
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    @Component({
        selector: 'artist-details',
        templateUrl: '../templates/detail.component.html'
    })
    export class DetailComponent {
        selectedartist: any;
        spotfyService: SpotfyService;
        artistDetails;
        constructor(spotfyService: SpotfyService) {
            this.spotfyService = spotfyService;
        }
        @Input()
        set artist(a:any) {
        // load the details of the given artist
        // a='detailedArtist' getting name of property not value ?
        this.selectedartist = a;

         this.isLoading=true;
        this.showArtistDetails=false;  
        var info = this.spotfyService.getDetails(a);
        info.subscribe(data=>{ 
            this.artistDetails = data;
            this.showArtistDetails=true;  
            this.isLoading=false;  
        });

}
    }
```

detail.component.html;

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="isLoading">
    Retrieveing artist info....
</div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="showArtistDetails">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <img class="img-circle" style="width:100%" src="{{artistDetails.images[0]?.url}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to see html content of detail.component.html, when the button in user.component.html clicked

Comment: I would suggest to tag it as angular 2 as it's not an typescript question.

Comment: @alekkowalczyk done..

Comment: I don't understand. What does showDetails() do? Why do you expect the template detail.component.html to show up in the template of the user component? And why is user inheriting from detail?

Comment: @JBNizet I want to call Details when an user clicked. So User and Detail, so due to call showDetails function of Detail component I derived User from it

Comment: This inheritance will not work, you should create the UserComponent as a composite with a child DetailComponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing inheritance. There is no reason for the user component to extend detail. A user is not a detail. Here's the important steps you need to follow:

1. Rename your components. Your user component seems to actually be an ArtistListComponent. Your detail component seems to actually be an ArtistDetailComponent. Using good names shows even more how inheritance is not applicable: an artist list is not an artist detail.
2. In your artist list component component, add a field named `detailedArtist`. When clicking one of the artists in the list, set the `detailedArtist` to the clicked artist.
3. In the template of the artist list component, display the detailed artist only if the `detailedArtist` is set, and pass that detailed artist as input to the ArtistDetailComponent:

   ```
   <artist-detail *ngIf="detailedArtist" [artist]="detailedArtist"></artist-detail>
   ```
4. In your ArtistDetailComponent add an `@Input()`-decorated property. Using a setter, you can know when the artist passed as input changes, and can thus load the detail of that artist from your backend:

   ```
   @Input()
   set artist(a: Artist) {
        // load the details of the given artist
   }
   ```

Comment: Hello, thanks for detailed answer I did everything you said and edited post based on your answer, I have problem with last step I think. can you check my edit, Thank you again

Comment: The `@Input()` must be on the setter. As I now did in my answer.

Comment: not it comes to set function but instead of value of artist.id, parameter value of set artist(a:any) "a='detailedArtist' " getting variable name of the property ? why this happen ?

Comment: Use the binding syntax, surround artist in brackets `[artist]="detailedArtist"`

Comment: I made a mistake. It's `[artist]="detailedArtist"`.

Comment: Thanks you its more than answer I really appreciated for your help